# getting data mysql and dynamic pages

Tags: php, mysql

```
$menu=$_GET[menu];
if (empty($menu))
    {
    $menu==1;
    }

$menusql= "select * from menu order by menu_id asc";
$menusorgu= mysql_query($menusql);
while (@$menusonuc = mysql_fetch_array($menusorgu)) 
{
    if ($menusonuc[menu_id]= $menu)
    {
    echo "<li class=\"active first\"><a href=\"portal.php?menu=\"$menusonuc[menu_id]\"\">$menusonuc[menu]</a></li>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<li><a href=\"portal.php?menu=\"$menusonuc[menu_id]\"\">$menusonuc[menu]</a></li>";
    }
}
```

In database i have menu_id and menu
"active first" class is shows you where you are
this codes writes all menus but cant show "active first" class 
Can someone help me?

Comment: Follow coding convention. The indentation is not good. Its quite unreadable.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: why do you think the current indentation isn't a convention? There is no single and the only correct code convention, and the used one - is just another one you personally don't like.

Comment: @zerkms I couln't actually find how braces after `if` followed any consistent convention

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: at the first level - shift, at the second - don't. Weird, but why not? Code convention could describe any weird logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `=` where you should use `==` and used `==` where you should use only `=` and you forgot to use quotations around name of array keys. Try this code instead of yours (it's modified):

```
$menu = $_GET["menu"];
if (empty($menu)) {
    $menu = 1;
}

$menusql = "select * from menu order by menu_id asc";
$menusorgu = mysql_query($menusql);
while ($menusonuc = mysql_fetch_array($menusorgu)) {
    if ($menusonuc["menu_id"] == $menu) {
        echo "<li class='active first'><a href='portal.php?menu={$menusonuc["menu_id"]}'>{$menusonuc['menu']}</a></li>";
    } else {
        echo "<li><a href='portal.php?menu={$menusonuc["menu_id"]}'>{$menusonuc["menu"]}</a></li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Put some significant word with your answer. NOT just throw code

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im I did. Thanks for the notice

Answer (score 1):

it must be `==` in if condition

```
if ($menusonuc["menu_id"] == $menu){
..
}
```

Comment: I understand you just copied the code, but it's not a big job to add couple of quotes

Answer (score 1):

Basic syntax trap, you're using `=` where you should be using `==`

```
if ($menusonuc[menu_id] == $menu)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use  equality operator `==` instead of  assignment operator `=` in `$menusonuc[menu_id]= $menu`

Your code has some other problems.

1. **Array index must be quoted**. SO `$menusonuc[menu_id]` should be `$menusonuc['menu_id']`
2. Dont use `@` in front of a simple variable. It does not make any sense. You can use it in front of a function call or an expression. `@$arr[$index]`  makes sense.
3. Dont use `@` at all. This [error control operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) is very slow. Besides it hides errors and make it difficult to debug.

Comment: "This error suppression operator is very slow" --- it's actually not the reason to stop using it at all.

Comment: Another this is "it hides errors and make it difficult to debug". What  are other reason?

Comment: I'd swap that statements. At first place it makes development harder. And... there is no second place, just remove a thing about its speed ))

Comment: "What are other reason?" -- it makes debugging/maintaining more tricky.